# How do I trigger a javascript method when I select an item while using the Webdriver Select Class?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, select, automation

I'm using the Select class via Webdriver. The following code actually selects the correct item, but the javascript is NOT triggered. I have tried onClick, onselect, and onfocus and none of them trigger the javascript function when selecting it via the Select class.

Manually it does trigger it.

How can I use the Select Class and also trigger the function?  I appreciate any help you can give me!

---

```
<select name="elements" id="elements">
                    <option selected onClick="hideAll()">Select One</option>
                    <option value="buttons" onClick="changeElement('buttons')">Buttons</option>
                    <option value="dropdowns" on onClick="changeElement('dropdowns')">Dropdowns</option>
                </select>
```

---

```
final WebElement selectMenu = driver.findElement(By.id("elements"));

final Select select = new Select(selectMenu);

select.selectByVisibleText("Buttons");
```

---

[Automated Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Uhl5.jpg)
[Manual Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiLQD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

What I found is that the option tags that have the javascript method running onClick, etc, won't work when using the Select class. It's like they are not considered HTML objects or something. I can't even use the tools to get the xpath.

But if I change the select tag to use the method, and pass in the value, the Select class will actually clicks it and trigger the method.

Now since the option tag can use the onClick(), onSelect(), etc... methods, it may be we see this in the field and it may cause problems. But at least we know about it.

Here's the new HTML version that works with the Select statement:

---

```
<select name="elements" onchange="changeElement(this.value)" id="elements">
                    <option id="elementsHide" selected value="none">Select One</option>
                    <option id="elementsButtons" value="buttons">Buttons</option>
                    <option id="elementsDropdowns" value="dropdowns" >Dropdowns</option>
                </select>
```